# Browser won't reflect changes in JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm recently learning how to host a local web server, and lately I've been dealing with a very frustrating issue. My browser sees the changes I make in my HTML and CSS file, but it won't respond at all to my JS file. They're all in the same folder under index.js, index.html, and main.css. It's super frustrating and hard for me to practice when I can't even tell if what I'm doing is working. Does anyone see any issues with my code that might explain this? I have the cache disabled, so I know that's not it.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>

        <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
            <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
            <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
            <button type="submit">Add item</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
'use strict';
/* global $ */

function addItem(){
  $('input').prop('required');
  $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    const userTextElement = $(event.currentTarget).find('#shopping-list-entry');

  helpAdd(userTextElement.val());
});
}

function checkItem(){
  $('.shopping-list').on('click', '.shopping-item-toggle', event => {
  event.preventDefault();   
});
}

function deleteItem(){
  $('.shopping-list').on('click', '.shopping-item-delete', event => {
  event.preventDefault();       
});
}

function helpCheck(item) {
  if($(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class') === 'shopping- 
  item shopping-item__checked')
  {
  $(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class','shopping-item');
  }   
 else{
 $(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class','shopping-item 
 shopping-item__checked');
 }
}

function helpAdd(itemName){
  $( '.shopping-list').append(` <li>
  <span class="shopping-item">${itemName}</span>
  <div class="shopping-item-controls">
  <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
    <span class="button-label">check</span>
  </button>
  <button class="shopping-item-delete">
    <span class="button-label">delete</span>
  </button>
 </div>
</li>`);
}

$(addItem);
$(checkItem);
$(deleteItem);
```

Comment: make sure you clear the cache, then reload the page

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried Shift clicking the refresh button?"

Comment: Try hard refreshing the page, control + shift + r

Comment: I'm using Chrome. And yes I have, no amount of refreshing fixes anything. Sometimes if I completely close out of the page and re-open it, it will work, but most of the time it doesn't work.

Comment: have you inspected the console? If there is an error, the script arrives at that point and you may not see the changes on the site

Comment: @user615274 nothing shows up in the console :/ I've tried copying and pasting code from old projects where I KNOW there aren't any errors and where something should show up, and it doesn't even reflect those changes.

Comment: could you show the content of index.js? in order to try to figure out the problem. I could be logic

Comment: @user615274 sure I just added the JS code to the original post

Comment: *"I'm recently learning how to host a local web server"* What web server are you using, and is it caching your JS files?

Comment: Can you try finding your script file in Source inside console tab in chrome?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chrome:
Go to `DevTools(F12) > Network tab > mark Disable cache`

Then refresh the browser with `DevTools` window open.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are missing the element with class 'shopping-list' I just added as `<ul class="shopping-list"></ul>`

Please try this code

```js
'use strict';
/* global $ */

function addItem() {
    $('input').prop('required');
    $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const userTextElement = $(event.currentTarget).find('#shopping-list-entry');

        helpAdd(userTextElement.val());
    });
}

function checkItem() {
    $('.shopping-list').on('click', '.shopping-item-toggle', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

function deleteItem() {
    $('.shopping-list').on('click', '.shopping-item-delete', event => {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}

function helpCheck(item) {
    if ($(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class') === 'shopping-item shopping - item__checked')
    {
        $(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class', 'shopping-item');
    }   
 else {
        $(item.closest('li')).find('>:first-child').attr('class', 'shopping-item shopping - item__checked');
 }
}

function helpAdd(itemName) {
    $('.shopping-list').append(` <li>
  <span class="shopping-item">${itemName}</span>
  <div class="shopping-item-controls">
  <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
    <span class="button-label">check</span>
  </button>
  <button class="shopping-item-delete">
    <span class="button-label">delete</span>
  </button>
 </div>
</li>`);
}

$(addItem);
$(checkItem);
$(deleteItem);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
        <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
        <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" id="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli">
        <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list"></ul>
</div>
```